# Create Table from Google Cloud Workflows

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-composer

I have a Cloud SQL Postgres DB. In my Cloud Workflows Job I am pulling some data from bigquery and want to create around 50 tables based on the data (via a loop). However, I see no way to POST a CREATE TABLE statement from Cloud Workflows (or via http / curl) to the database instance. It seems that I cannot create tables.

I can also not really use an SDK (e.g. via Go) since there are multiple other steps involved that "should live" in Cloud Workflows only for this task. I would like to avoid to split this task.

Does anyone know how to do this? I googled everything....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud Workflows is an API orchestrator. I mean, you can only perform API call on each step.

So, if your database is API compliant, such as BigQuery, you can create a query job with only an API call and use the create table statement like that.

If your database, as legacy database PostgreSQL, MySQL or SQL Serveur, are TCP based, you must establish a TCP connection and then submit your statement.

---

Because Cloud Workflow is HTTP based, it's not possible. You have to create code that you can invoke by API call (Cloud Functions or Cloud Run for instance) and that performs that actions for you.